# Changing work directory to location of program in C on Linux

Tags: c, linux

If I have a script that, for whatever reason, needs the current working directory to be the directory that it is stored in, I can run `cd "$(dirname "${0}")"`. Is there some simple way to do this with a C program?

Answer (score 2):

`$0` in a shell script corresponds to `argv[0]` in a C program. However, if the command was found based on `PATH`, that approach won't work.

In Linux, you can check the `/proc/self/exe` pseudo-symlink to see which binary file the current process is executing. You can use [`readlink("/proc/self/exe", buffer, size)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readlink.2.html) to obtain the path to the current executable.

For example, you could use e.g.

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

/* Return the path to the directory the current executable
   resides in, as a dynamically allocated string.
   If an error occurs, returns NULL with errno set.
*/
char *exe_dir(void)
{
    size_t  size = 512, i, n;
    char   *path, *temp;

    while (1) {
        ssize_t  used;

        path = malloc(size);
        if (!path) {
            errno = ENOMEM;
            return NULL;
        }

        used = readlink("/proc/self/exe", path, size);

        if (used == -1) {
            const int saved_errno = errno;
            free(path);
            errno = saved_errno;
            return NULL;
        } else
        if (used < 1) {
            free(path);
            errno = EIO;
            return NULL;
        }

        if ((size_t)used >= size) {
            free(path);
            size = (size | 2047) + 2049;
            continue;
        }

        size = (size_t)used;
        break;
    }

    /* Find final slash. */
    n = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        if (path[i] == '/')
            n = i;

    /* Optimize allocated size,
       ensuring there is room for
       a final slash and a
       string-terminating '\0', */
    temp = path;
    path = realloc(temp, n + 2);
    if (!path) {
        free(temp);
        errno = ENOMEM;
        return NULL;
    }

    /* and properly trim and terminate the path string. */
    path[n+0] = '/';
    path[n+1] = '\0';

    return path;
}
```

Note that you do not necessarily need to use `chdir()` to change to that path; you can also open it using e.g. `open(path, O_PATH)` and use that file descriptor as a parameter to [`openat()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) and other *at() functions.

If the executable is very deep in the filesystem hierarchy, this may return NULL with `errno == ENAMETOOLONG`, because of the nature of this pseudo-symlink. The alternatives, like reading the path from `/proc/self/maps` or `/proc/self/smaps`, suffers from an unfixed kernel bug (I have reported) where paths with backslashes `\` get incorrectly escaped.

In any case, if `exe_dir()` returns NULL, I warmly suggest your program simply reports to the user that the directory the current executable resides in cannot be determined (possibly along with the cause, `strerror(errno)`), and aborts.

Answer (score 1):

[chdir](https://linux.die.net/man/2/chdir) -   change working directory

```
#include <unistd.h>

int chdir(const char *path);
```

`chdir()` changes the current working directory of the calling process to the directory specified in path.

Comment: Changing the current working directory fits into the question, but on its own it does not answer it. I know what `chdir()` does.

Comment: @Melab Your question is not clear. You want to change to a directory given a full path to a file name?